# CRM Plug-in Trace Log - logs only for sandbox mode

Tags: c#, logging, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I have this very simple plugin

```
 public class TestPlugin : IPlugin
  {
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
      ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
      tracingService.Trace("HelloWorld");
    }
  }
```

but the log is tracked only when the plugin is registered in `Sandbox`. When I select `None`, there is not any log from the plugin.
I've already found some threads about this problem, but no solution.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You might have seen [this community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/189346/plugin-trace-log-not-working-on-dynamics-crm-2016-on-premise), many users are affected by this behavior. That may be [the intended behavior by Microsoft](http://blog.intocrm.net/plug-in-trace-logs-outside-the-sandbox-2/).

See the comments from [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328574(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#write-to-the-tracing-service):

```
//Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
ITracingService tracingService =
    (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
```

But interestingly [MS documentation conflicts with that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328574(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#logging-and-tracing).

> Tracing is supported for sandboxed (partial trust) and full trust registered custom code and during synchronous or asynchronous execution.

Probably [this idea](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Write-to-the-Plug-in-Trace-Log-from-assemblies-outside-SandBox/idi-p/222339) will make the change, vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a trace log when you register in None mode and there is an error?  I have, sadly, had to throw Exceptions in my plugin code before to get a log file generated to see what is going on.

Not sure if that helps.